# Use and meaning of "over" in "move over to the corner"

Tags: phrase-usage

In the following sentence:

> We have to move the bookshelf from the middle of room over to the corner.

1. Is "over" used here as part of the phrase of "move over" or not?
2. If not, what is the meaning of "over" in this sentence?
3. What is the difference between the version with "over" and the one without "over"?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As the ELL Exchange is intended to help people learn to speak English better, please try to use proper capitalization, punctuation, and grammar wherever you're able; it helps improve everyone's understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. If you tell someone to "move over", that's using the phrasal verb. But in this example, it's just a verb and a not-so-near adverb.
2. It doesn't mean much at all. Once you have specified the "from" and "to" (origin and destination), it's redundant to say "over to".  You're not moving it "over" anything (except the floor, which it's already on). It's pretty clear you're not moving it up or down. You're moving it sideways.
3. No difference at all. See #2.

By the way:  "from the middle of room" should be "from the middle of the room"

Comment: I agree that it's not necessary, but I'll add that this is one of those odd cases where the "redundant" word sounds natural, not clunky. There's no harm in leaving it in (at least, not in AmE).

Comment: Thanks J.R.  Faji, I didn't mean to say there was anything wrong with leaving "over" in— just that one doesn't really lose anything semantically by omitting it.

Answer (score 0):

In the phrase *move over*, *move* is a verb and *over* is an adverb.

**over** See definition [Adverb 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/over) Also see: [Adverb 3b](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/over) in the first dictionary.

The same meanings are used in this sentence, no matter how many prepositional phrases you stick in. If you take all the prepositional phrases out, you get:

> We have to move the bookshelf over.

*Move* is a verb. *Over* is an adverb.

The difference in the sentence without *over* is that the adverb *over* is left out.

> We have to move the bookshelf.

Even if you phrase the sentence as

> We have to move over the bookshelf.

*Move* is a verb. *Over* is an adverb. (*Over* would be the preposition in the prepositional phrase *over the bookshelf*, but that is not how we are using *over* in the sentence. Otherwise, it is not the bookshelf that is moving, but the subject.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and Adverb 3b. describe the over as:  To another often specified place or position: Move your chair over toward the fire.  I have understood it's usage.