# "walks over to" vs "walks to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A man walked over to us. "Are you an actor?" he asked me.

What is the meaning of "over" here? Can we omit it and say "A man walked to us"?

Comment: The adverbial preposition ***over*** is used to [express passage or trajectory across an area](https://www.encyclopedia.com/places/britain-ireland-france-and-low-countries/british-and-irish-political-geography/over) (in your case, that's the area between "us" and wherever he was before he started walking towards us). It makes no difference whether you use ***to, toward, towards*** or ***over to*** or ***up to*** (sometimes even ***down to*** or ***out to*** or similar). They all describe the same movement, and it's really just a stylistic choice how you express it.

Comment: ...Except we wouldn't use ***up to*** or ***down to*** if we and the man were at obviously different heights in the *opposite* direction to that implied by the relevant preposition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference among "come" "come up" "come over" and "come around"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72307/what-is-difference-among-come-come-up-come-over-and-come-around) Also [What is the difference of "go to", "go over to" and "go up to" to "X's place"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197491/) and [Use and meaning of "over" in "move over to the corner"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51460/), among others.